# Android app that analyze the calls and messages and generate a report

Tags: gratis, android, phone, sms

Report the number of calls and messages (sms) in the android phone (at least Android 4 and above + the phone was original and not rooted at all) and category them based on numbers, time, etc. The Android app preferable gratis. Great to have - to shows the stats in graphical mode (such as pie chart, line chart, etc)

Comment: Can the phone be rooted, or not?

Comment: Not many apps left in that sector, and I'm not sure which one (if any) covers all your needs – but be welcome to take a look at [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_statistics) while waiting for recommendations.

Comment: @Izzy, Thanks, I have added my answer but the system says that it need half a day before I can mark as the answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The android app that is suitable in this scenario is - 'Advanced Call History'.

This app is one of the apps in the corresponding app listing by Izzy (moderator for software recommendation stackexchange site). Thanks Izzy for coming out with this wonderful app listing.

'Advanced Call History' app can read call and sms log and generate reports grouped by caller name or phone number.

'Advanced Call History' app, developed by Dinko Ivkovic, is currently not updated since 2014 and its last version is 1.15. It would be great if anyone can further enhance this app to include graph and chart.

[image]

Comment: Note that *Advanced Call History* to my knowledge is only [available via Aptoide](https://m.aptoide.com/app/6025834), as the app was unlisted from Play in 1/2018. Its developer is no longer active, and the code not available (to my knowledge), so there hardly will be any further development.